# ExtJS 4 Column Layout in FieldSet

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I think the example code I have should result in the two textareas behind horizontally next to each other, like this:

```
[textfield] [textfield]
```

not:

```
[textfield]
[textfield]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aKCfh/

What am I forgetting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have the ExtJS stylesheet included

Here is a link:

http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-4.1.0-gpl/resources/css/ext-all-gray.css

Comment: Thanks. That's why it's not working in jsFiddle. Not sure if that will fix the issue in my app.